# Angular ng-grid disable automatic generating columns

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, dynamic-columns

I am using angular `ng-grid` with a lot of columns, like 100+ columns. This grid's default feature is to remove from html the columns that are out of browser window, and they are automatically generated when user scrolls the grid. Is there any setting for disabling the automatic generating columns, that html contains all the columns?

Answer (score 0):

[columnVirtualizationThreshold](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions#properties_columnfooterheight) and [virtualizationThreshold](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions#properties_useexternalsorting) are exactly what you were looking for. If you assign them a small number (let say 10), they will ensure that on a moment just 10 rows and 10 columns will be loaded.

I'm also using ui-grid for a large dataset and by doing this, you can easily mess with 1000 rows data and 500 columns.